# Clickable link within NSMutableAttributedString needs to show another viewcontroller / storyboard

Tags: swift, uitextview, nsmutableattributedstring, swift5

I have a UITextView and NSMutableAttributedString which has a clickable link. I need this to show another storyboard but not quite sure how I could do this.

What I have so far works for external links but not a storyboard. Any help would be appreciated.

Not sure if the below code is the best way to approach it or not?

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Already have an account? Log in")
        attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: "", range: NSRange(location: 25, length: 6))

        textView.attributedText = attributedString

    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL)

        return false
    }


}
```

EDIT

After NikR answer I've updated my code to the following but still no success. It's still loading Google.

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Already have an account? Log in")
        attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: "https://google.com", range: NSRange(location: 25, length: 6))

        textView.attributedText = attributedString
        textView.isSelectable = true
        textView.isEditable = false

        textView.delegate = self

    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {

        let loginViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginViewController")
        show(loginViewController, sender: self)

        return true
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's the right way.
But not call:

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL)
```

Simply initiate your VC and show/present it:

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()
show( vc, sender: self )
```

And don't forget to:

```
textView.delegate = self
```

Comment: The controller I want to show uses the same story board so I dont think I can use the ```instantiateInitialViewController ```

So I used ```let loginViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController")```

Should this still work?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Comment: I get this message in my console ```Could not find any actions for URL  without any result.```

Comment: Try to set some real URL in value with "https://", seems that it tries to parse url but cannot without a scheme

Comment: I tried that so if I pass ```https://google.com``` when the login link is clicked it opens safari and goes to google. It doesn't show my LoginViewController

Comment: Check that textView.delegate = self

Comment: Yeah I've added ```textView.delegate = self ``` i've updated my question to have the full code in there from your answer.

Comment: @craigib, you should return false from textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool . It will not pass control to iOS and allows you to handle it by youself

Comment: This worked, along with your original answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can set to your textView:

```
textView.dataDetectorTypes = .link
```

Answer (score 0):

You should enable isSelectable and disable isEditable for your text view.

```
textView.isSelectable = true
textView.isEditable = false
```

Don't forget to do this

```
textView.delegate = self
```

This Delegate method will use to handle click

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {

}
```

Comment: When I add ```textView.delegate = self``` to my viewDidfLoad I get an error ```Cannot assign value of type 'HomeViewController' to type 'UITextViewDelegate?'```

Comment: Replace 
class HomeViewController: UIViewController 
with class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate

for implement delegate methods for  UITextView.

Comment: Or Just under your implementation extension HomeViewController: UITextViewDelegate { //... }

Comment: @NikR yes we can also add extension for UITextViewDelegate under class implementation